# Java Apache HttpClient EnityUtils block

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

I am currently working on a project which is using Apache HttpClient 4.1.2 and it retrieves some data from a website.

What the application does: it goes to a webpage and then goes to the next (found) pages until it reaches the end (e.g.: go to page 1 -> finds 20  more pages -> go to every next 20 pages). The problem is that it gets stuck on retrieving some random pages and it doesn't continue the crawl.

Here is some code:

```
DefaultHttpClient mainHttp;
HttpPost post;
HttpResponse response;
HttpEntity entity;
String s;
int curPage = 1;
int index = 0;
boolean ok = true;

...

while (ok) { 
  response = mainHttp.execute(post);
  entity = response.getEntity();
  if (entity != null) {
    System.out.println("Enter " + curPage);
    s = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    System.out.println("Exit " + curPage);
    index = s.indexOf("[" + curPage + "]");
    if (index > 0) {
      parseContent();
    } else {
      ok = false;
    }                
  }
}
```

On the debug window is shows something like this:

```
Enter 1
Exit 1
.
.
.
Enter n
```

I am also using a http request analyzer and I saw that on the page that stucks, the data is not retrieved completely (it doesn't reach the `</html>` or the end of the page).

What can I do to skip or retry downloading the data in such cases? Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

**LE:**

The actual settings were:

```
mainHttp.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(1, true));
mainHttp.getParams().setParameter("http.connection-manager.timeout", 15000);
mainHttp.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 15000);
mainHttp.getParams().setParameter("http.connection.timeout", 15000);
```

where `15000` is the timeout in miliseconds.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DefaultMethodRetryHandler retryhandler = new DefaultMethodRetryHandler(1, true);
mainHttp.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, retryhandler);
```

Source: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html (**Method recovery**)

But this is only if there were any exceptions that occurred, try checking for *IOExceptions* every time you make a request

Comment: Nope. Still nothing. I have addes also a timeout and still nothing happens. :(

Comment: But are you actually sure that you are getting EVERY page in response from server?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure. It downloads n-1 pages and for the n-th page it stucks at xx%.

Comment: OK. then the problem could be in consequent requests.. what if you try to make requests async or in thread every page and a parseContent(); function execute on demand, if thread does not work, try async task. I had some kind of similar problem, but in my case my HTTPClient were dying every time, i did something like threaded client. ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,
    schemeRegistry); then you just set parameters and schemes and make your client like: client = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);

Comment: @IonutUngureanu or better look in here: http://droidsnip.blogspot.com/2011/10/custom-http-client-android.html#more for some code. Hope it can help

Comment: What do you mean by "Async requests?". My app is (currently) doing a new connection after a previous connection released. My question is WHY it stucks at lets say 80% and HttpClient does nothing (it doesn't close connection, nor retry it).

Comment: I have changed the logic of my app. The description is in the edited post. Thanks anyway!